# Issue with adding statusbar to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that extends JFrame and packs two Jpanels onto it one being a statusbar JPanel and other being a contentDisplay Panel.

Based on the changes made in the contentDisplay panel, I need to dynamically change the label text in the status bar Jpanel. To achieve this, I've created a separate class for statusbar Panel with the following code.

```
public class StatusBar extends JPanel {
    JLabel status;
    /** Creates a new instance of StatusBar */
    public StatusBar() {
        super();
        status = new JLabel("Ready and Running");
        this.add(status);       
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);            
        g.drawString(status.getText(), 10,10);
      }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        status.setText("Status : " + message);          
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I have created an object of this class and added it onto the JFrame. The panel is added but when I call the setMessage() method in the subsequent implementation of the frame, the message is not getting repainted i.e. the status panel is not refreshing the status message. How can I solve this issue?

PS: I donot want to revalidate() and repaint() my parent JFrame for every change in status. I just want the status panel to be refreshed every time as the above code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need the `paintComponent` call...  This should do:

```
public class StatusBar extends JPanel {
    JLabel status;

    public StatusBar() {
        this.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0 ) ) ;
        status = new JLabel("Ready and Running");
        this.add(status);       
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        status.setText("Status : " + message);          
    }
}
```

Or indeed you could just use a class that extends `JLabel`

```
public class StatusBar extends JLabel {

    public StatusBar() {
        setMessage( "Ready and Running" );
    }

    public void setMessage( String message ) {
        setText( message ) ;        
    }        
}
```

Comment: No I already tried this. setText was not working because I am not calling this from the JFrame class alone. I need to call the setMessage inside different classes that are used by JFrame.  

If I do so, the text would be set for the label but it wouldnt get displayed on the frame.

Comment: Don't you think this sort of information would have been helpful when you asked the question?  Please edit your question to give as much information about your actual problem as you can.  It seems your problem is more related to __how__ you are using the class

Comment: @Vamsi, it doesn't matter what calls the setMessage method, this is the  appropriate way to handle the issue.  If this doesn't work for you then your problem is actually elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

not updating of the gui is a general know issue, in this [tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5e_multithreading.html) is explained exactly what is causing your problem.